# Allowing external users to receive Change notifications for calendar events in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I have this setup:

Accessing my Organization with Client Credentials Flow, and enabled Calendars.ReadWrite to read "Read calendars in all mailboxes".

email: aleksander@organization.com

Created an Webhook for resource to subscribe for created,updated,deleted:

```
            'changeType' => 'created,updated,deleted',
            'notificationUrl' => 'url',
            'resource' => '/users/'.$this->email.'/calendars/'.$this->calendarId.'/events',
            'expirationDateTime' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(4230)->toIso8601String(),
            'clientState' => 'Secret',
        ];
```

This works fine if the calendar i'am subscribing to is created and owned by my user.

But I want to subscribe to the shared calendars with me, lets say an resource or shared calendar from another organization.

When others have shared a calendar with me, I can create the subscriptions successfully, but there is no events coming to my notificationUrl.

Is this not supported? The permission on my shared calendars is "Can see all details".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was working after all. Just that these events came like 1 hour later than my personal calendar. Will need to look into this.

Tips to others, verify that you have enabled Calendars.ReadWrite for your application if authenticating as administrator.